# Primefaces 5.1: @this ajax update not working anymore

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm having a little application with a selectOneMenu which needs to update the selected value in the backing bean. Easy thing. I used Primefaces 4 and the code looks like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="customersMenu"
            value="#{customerController.selectedCustomer}" style="float:right"
            converter="#{customerConverter}">
            <p:ajax event="change" update="@this, :tabview" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" Kunde auswählen" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{customerController.customers}"
                var="customer" itemLabel="#{customer.name}" itemValue="#{customer}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

With the ajax update on change the backing bean is updated correctly and a tabview is updated correctly too.
Now I replaced the primefaces4.jar with the primefaces5.jar and this is not working anymore. When checking with FireBug in Bugzilla I can see a ominous error saying: 'TypeError: PrimeFaces.Expressions is undefined'. Anyone got that too?

I played with the settings and found that the '@this' in ajax update seems to cause the error. I checked the migration guide, should be working - shouldn't it?

Anyway, I suceeded with removing '@this' and adding a ' onchange="submit();"' to my selectonemenu. The bean is now updated. I don't understand why, can anyone tell me?

Comment: Try to remove the comma after @this - blank seperates the two parts to update

Comment: Not sure but I think the errormessage can appear if the method is ambigous. So check if both jars are on the server.

Comment: Removing the comma leads to same error message. I checked that the libs are not duplicated. Thanks for your suggestions, but problem is not solved.

Comment: I now got a obscure error saying 'TypeError: b is undefined' in 'http:..../faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.1 line 14 > eval' when updating the tabview from the customerMenu selectOne menu. I'm confused and irritated, don't understand this and can't find anything on the internet about it :( Any ideas?